# How To Unsubscribe From Emails That Do Not Give You Means To Do That?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

Sometimes somebody subscribes my email to their list without any of my permission which gives him convenience of spamming my inbox. I know there are email extractors but never heard of email subscriber programs. Usually you deal with honest people who had your permission to subscribe to their list but sometimes it's people you have never heard about that send their emails without option to unsubscribe, the link that usually resides on the bottom of permission based marketing emails.

What are other ways to deal with this annoyance except marking it as spam every time? Should I take time consuming option to look through source of email to search for unknown person's email provider and submit complaint? Here can lie another problem and it is where unknown sender uses his own server-side email autoresponder.

Any suggestions or tips?

**Edit:** How can this question be on hold if SuperUser even has tags for my question?

Comment: "Usually you deal with honest people who had your permission to subscribe to their list" hahahahahhahaa.. ohh that's funny.. :D  You've heard of [spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(electronic)) right? ;)

Comment: @techie007 Well I am not denying that even people you have subscribed to can start sending you excess emails but at least you have option **to unsubscribe** at the bottom.

Comment: Spammers usually do not actually give you a legit unsubscribe link. Sometimes it's actually just a way for the spammer to build a list of addresses that are known to be good (because you replied or clicked a link). :/  Anyhow, if you don't want mail form a certain list, why not just block them in your spam/junk-mail filter and/or in your email client?

Comment: Just because you can find tags that match your question does not make it on topic. You can, in fact, read `[email]` with your computer and configure your client to do `[spam-prevention]`, but your question doesn't have anything to do with computer software itself. It's about marketing schemes and how humans operate mailing lists.

Comment: @techie007 Block their emails that are already in spam/junk folder?

Comment: @slhck Right. What is appropriate SE section for my question?

Comment: None, really, I'm afraid, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick tip that I use for all of my email signup stuff.
If you're using gmail you can add a "+nonsense" after your email address when signing up for stuff. for example if my email was joe@gmail.com and I was signing up for superuser.com I could make my email "joe+superuser@gmail.com" that way if superuser ever signs me up for spam emails I could simply filter them by sent to by saying if sent to joe+superuser@gmail.com then send to spam and skip inbox. These are all options in gmail, I'm not sure of support outside of that though.

Comment: I love this capability, but some sites unfortunately will mark e-mail addresses with a '+' in them as invalid, which is very annoying.

Comment: @th3dude Really, bummer. Didn't know this but what would work I think is doing similar thing what **jeruntime** suggested above for server-side email platforms.